# Generic enum conform to ExpressibleByNilLiteral in swift

Tags: swift, generics, enums, option-type

I have an enumeration defined as:

```
enum Context<T> {
    case some(T)
    case error(Error)
    case none
}
```

To make it expressible by nil, I've created this extension:

```
extension Context: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {
    init(nilLiteral: ()) {
        self = .none
    }
}
```

Then I have another class that exposes a method that should take as an argument the Context:

```
func start<T>(context: Context<T>)
```

If I try to use it passing nil as a context the compiler shows me an error saying:

```
Generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred
```

I've already seen some answer about it, but they don't seem to work.
I do not understand if it is not possible to do or if I'm doing in it in wrong way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type inferrer needs to determine `T` and it can not possibly do so from seeing `nil` (or `.none`, for that matter) alone -- which type should it choose?

You need to make `T` concrete, e.g. by

```
start(context: nil as Context<Int>)
```

Note again that passing `.none` has the same problem so the issue is not with `ExpressibleByNilLiteral` at all.

In real use, other parameters or even the return value may be used to determine `T`. For instance, if you have a function

```
func get<T>(context: Context<T>) throws -> T?
```

then lines like

```
let v: Int? = get(context: nil)
```

work perfectly well.

---

Side note: why use a `nil` literal as alias for `.none`? Using the latter avoids confusion while reading your code: `let v: Context<Int> = nil` is, on first sight, invalid Swift.